# How to change the active colour of the selected item in NavBarDropdown of react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am using the react-bootstrap NavdropDown component from [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/). I had used it properly but I am unable to set the custom background colour of the navdropdow-items when its in normal & active i.e. selected state .

Like I would like to change from `blue` to any other colour when option is selected as shown in image.[image]

how can I do so ? (even using css can also help if there's no inbuilt class/attribute for this in bootstrap).

**Navbar.js**

```
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/master">Hi {user.sub}</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .

            <NavDropdown drop="down-centered" menuVariant="dark"  title="3P-Verticals" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
              {
                verticals_3p.map((item)=> {
                  return(
                    <NavDropdown.Item key={item.val}>
                      <Nav.Link onClick={()=>props.setTenantName(item.val)}>{item.label}</Nav.Link>
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                  )
                })
              }  
            </NavDropdown>
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
```

I tried this in `App.css` but its **not** working.

```
#navbarScrollingDropdown:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `<NavDropdown>` that has an ID of `navbarScrollingDropdown` whereas it's the `<NavDropdown.Item>` that becomes active when selected. Also with how react-boostrap renders the DOM you end up with the following HTML:

```
<div menuvariant="dark" class="nav-item show dropdown">
  <a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" role="button">3P-Verticals</a>
  <div aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown" class="dropdown-menu show" style="margin: 0px;">
    <a href="#action/3.1" class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
    <a href="#action/3.2" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
    <a href="#action/3.3" class="dropdown-item active">Something</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider" role="separator"></div>
    <a href="#action/3.4" class="dropdown-item">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

so even if you used the CSS selector `#navbarScrollingDropdown .active` it wouldn't work as the popup menu div sits outside of the menu item element with the ID `navbarScrollingDropdown`.

You could override the CSS selector that is used by Bootstrap:

```
.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

Here's a working [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-mccarthy-vm8qtq?file=/src/App.css).